# Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA 14) Generating Code from class model for C# but it keeps defaulting to Java

Tags: c#, code-generation, enterprise-architect

I have been using Sparx EA for years.  Mostly with Java, but a few years ago I used the round-trip feature for a C# project.  It appears Sparx has changed the user interface and I cannot for the life of me find how to generate C# code.  It keeps defaulting to Java.

I tried following their documentation but it may be a bit dated, as I didn't see the same options.  So I poked around a bit.  I found the Programming Languages Datatypes and selected C# for the product.  That didn't work.  I also tried Manage Project Options and set the Default Language for Code Generation to C# but that didn't work either.

What is the secret?

Comment: Docs for you version... [Language Options](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/languageoptions.html) ... [Configuration Settings](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/codeengineeringsettings.html)

Comment: I found at the link you provided this link: [Language Options][https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/languageoptions.html] I was able to follow this `Configure > Model > Options > Source Code Engineering > <language name>` but that still didn't write C# classes.

Comment: It looks like there are User and Model options, have you checked them both? [Source Code Engineering Options](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/generaloptions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Set language in a single class

In EA each class has a code generation language feature you can change.
[image]

### Default Language setting

You can set the default language using the option
**Configure | Model | Options | Source code Engineering**
[image]

### Change language in existing model

In order to change the code generation for classes in an an existing model, use the option
**Develop | Preferences | Options | Reset Source Language**
[image]

This answers has been written for the current version of EA (15.2). Menu locations might be different in v14, but the same options are available.

Comment: For v14, The Reset Source Language is located on the Code ribbon in the Options menu.